# Activity lifecycle when launched from a pending intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

Activity `A` starts activity `B` (using `startActivityForResult()`) in its `onResume()`.

`B` in turn shows a Dialog `D`. When user selects an option in Dialog, `B` returns the result to `A` which process the result and finishes.

All this is working fine when `A` is triggered from another activity in the app. However, if `A` is launched as a pending intent from a notification (triggered from a service), the dialog `D` is shown. However, `onStop()` is called immediately on `A` even before user can select anything on the dialog and before `B` finishes. Hence dialog results are never passed back to `A`.

The configurations are as per the documentation here [Set up a special activity PendingIntent](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation.html#ExtendedNotification)

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```
    <activity android:name=".A"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:taskAffinity=""
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Transparent">
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".B"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Transparent">
    </activity>
```

This is how pending intent is created and notification is sent.

```
    Intent authIntent = new Intent(context, A.class);
    authIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingAuthIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    context,
                    0,
                    authIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );

    builder.setContentIntent(pendingAuthIntent);
    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nm.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
```

How can I make `A` wait for `B` to finish.

Comment: Don't completely understand. If `A` launches `B`, then `A` will no longer be visible and `onStop()` may be called. This is no problem. When `B` returns the results to `A`, `onStart()` will be called again on `A`.